# Bulk file rename in Vim Visual Block Mode

Tags: regular-expression, visual-block

I am using VIM Renamer plugin to bulk rename files,
I want to replace

```
E008_r5_Haz_Area_Class NAT GAS.pdf
E009_r4_Haz_Area_Class.pdf
E010_r4_Haz_Area_Class MP STEAM.pdf
E011_r3_Haz_Area_Class.pdf
E012_r3_Haz_Area_Class.pdf
E013_r3_Haz_Area_Class.pdf
```

with

```
E008_NG_Hazd Area Class_R2.pdf
E009_MDEA_Hazd Area Class_R4.pdf
E010_SYNGAS _ REFRIG_Hazd Area Class_R4.pdf
E011_Reform _Hazd Area Class_R3.pdf
E012_Air Cooler_Hazd Area Class_R3.pdf
E013_Air Cooler_Hazd Area Class_R3.pdf
```

Process is as below,

1. column mode, select complete line except ".pdf".
2. column replace new names as files are in order only.
3. Issue :Ren command to replace all file names.

I was manually doing it for single lines but I have more than 1000 files to rename. Appreciate any help here, I want to learn vim syntax but managing chemical engineering work and learning vim is too steep for me. Appreciate if I can have little explanation.

Comment: There's no clear pattern in the replacements, so I'm not sure I see a way to come up with a `:substitute` or similar command to automate this. I'm not to sure what "column mode" is—do you mean visual-block mode (the mode entered by `<C-v>`)?

Comment: Thanks for reply, i missed to capture first line. before and after cases are same only except file name is different. Column mode is same as visual block mode.

Comment: Can you be more explicit how to translate the input to the output?  For example, the last line (`E013_r3_Haz_Area_Class.pdf`) rearranges the words in the input but also adds the words `Air Cooler` -- where does that come from?